# div to be displayed in a nav tab

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I'm using navbar for tabs with jquerymobile .
as you will notice my tabs are generated through  jsonp.

I'm facing a  problem when trying to load a div inside a tab . internal href doesn't seem to work .

what I want to do is , for example the  with list loads when I change to tab x.

```js
<script>
        function order() {
            var output = [];
         
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://192.168.22.102/me1.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: "mycallback",
                success: function (data) {
                    jsonArray = data;
                    jsonArray = data;
                    var ch = "";
                         for (i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
                        ch = ch + '<li><a href="#'+jsonArray[i].id+ '" data-ajax="false" onclick="clk();">' + jsonArray[i].nom + '</a></li>'
                    }
                    ch = '<div data-role="navbar"><ul>' + ch + '</a></ul></div>';
                    var s = $(ch).appendTo('.ui-content')
                   
                    alert(ch);
                    $('#lm').append('<div data-role="navbar"></div>').trigger('create');



                }
            });



        }
</script>
```

```html
<body onload="order('');">
    

    <div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="content" id="lm">


  <div id="1">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">so</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

       
 </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-postion="fixed">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
        
     
 
        </div>
```

*update*
I've solved the issue by adding a personal click handler

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="navbar"] a', 'click', function () {
$(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
$('.content_div').hide();
$('#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();
return false;});
```

Comment: Can you give us the response of your ajax call ? (the json)

Comment: I am not sure of what I am saying, but from what I've tried with your code, you could remove  .append('<div data-role="navbar">' + output.join() + '</div>') so it becomes $('#lm').trigger('create');

Not sure why you use output[].

And you have a unstarted <a> there : ch = '<div data-role="navbar"><ul>' + ch + '</a></ul></div>';

Comment: the json-->"mycallback([{"id":"1","nom":"pizza"},{"id":"2","nom":"sandwich"},{"id":"3","nom":"drinks"},{"id":"4","nom":"lunch"},{"id":"5","nom":"dinner"}])"

Comment: thx for the feedback @RomainDerie. the json call qorks fine and the tabs are built perfectly . my question is how to load a specific div inside a tab .

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/k8fgbr6z3/ this is how my window looks like

Comment: You have to use tabs + navbar

Comment: well when i add tabs to lm , i get duplicate navbars .

Comment: I don't, but I can't manage to make the content div works as they should : all 3 are shown [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxna4L9v/3/)

The output code is good, the navbar and tabs are rightly construct, but the tabs content are not enhanced because we should only see one of the 3, and the requested one should be shown when you click on the related tab

Comment: can  you please give me your code ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sxna4L9v/5/

I skiped the ajax part since I can't request your file and put an equivalent data

Comment: your code offered a great start , i cant get the tabs working right though